# below is the data which I need to pass dynamically using bean shell prepocessor in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

```
List[0].Id  : 0111
[0].Name : Henry
List[0].Description : abc
List[1].Id  : 0112
[1].Name : Hank
List[1].Description : xyz
```

I need values 0111, Henry, etc as variables.

Comment: Hi @abeer, what is your question/problem?

Comment: I am using: sampler.addArgument("List["+i+"].Id",vars.get("Id"+j)):   but getting void as response. can u help with the beanshell script

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like a raw unstructured data so it's better to use i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor or Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/) to work with it.
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting.

Going forward if you need further support consider providing the data **exactly** as it is followed by the screenshot of the desired [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration as in its current form your question is absolutely unclear